# Error at Docker Desktop start-up in Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm starting Docker in my Windows OS and after the loading of its Linux Containers WSL2 backend, it is giving me this dialogue-box. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error?

[Error dialogue-box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjUs6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From `Docker`'s settings, change the location of the configuration files (or folder) to anther partition (do not use the one that the OS is installed on). Use `D:` partition if the OS is installed on the `C:` partition.

Comment: What to do if I do not have a separate partition? Actually it's in my laptop and there I only have one partition i.e. the C: drive where there's windows OS and docker is also installed there.

Comment: Right-click the start button and choose: `Disk Management`, after that right-click the `C:` partition and select `Shrink`.